# Lambda - Nested forEach operations on multiple List<T> very slow

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've got a large operation that I'm trying to accomplish using LINQ by merging multiple collections into one (callQuery in the snippet below) and then updating another list from the merged collection (dataCopy).

The reason the code has been structured this way is to process these calculations in memory (even though some of this may be better suited as a database operation) since the data is coming in from SQL and NoSQL DB sources.

It works but it's horrendously slow. It takes over 10 seconds to complete with the lists of the following sizes:

- dataCopy = 397 rows (this object is to get updated in the loop)
- callQuery = 792 (this object is a projected merge of SQL/NoSQL datasets)
- holidayStructureList = 11 (object contains info on whether a day is a holiday)
- HourValuePairs = 24 (object will always be 24 values and contains hour:value pairs for a particular day)

Am I going about this completely wrong or is there something in my code that's throwing things off?

```
dataCopy.ForEach(dc =>
            {
                //Apply Cost and Rate to each Hour:Value pair 
                dc.HourValuePairs.ForEach(dchv => {
                      var matchQuery =
                            (
                                //If there were holidays...
                                holidayStructureList != null
                                ?
                                    //If the day is a holiday
                                    (holidayStructureList.Select(h => h.Date.Date).Contains(dc.Date.Date)) 
                                    ?
                                        //Then ensure that the IsHoliday flag is set
                                        callQuery.Where(
                                            cq => cq.Date.Date == dc.Date.Date && cq.PDay.ToLower() == "holiday"
                                            && dc.Date >= cq.StartDate && dc.Date <= cq.EndDate
                                            && dchv.h >= cq.ItemStartHour && dchv.h <= cq.ItemEndHour
                                            && cq.IsHoliday == true
                                        )
                                        :
                                            //Else, it's a regular day
                                            callQuery.Where(
                                                cq => cq.Date.Date == dc.Date.Date && cq.PDay.ToLower() == dc.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToLower()
                                                && dc.Date >= cq.StartDate && dc.Date <= cq.EndDate
                                                && dchv.h >= cq.ItemStartHour && dchv.h <= cq.ItemEndHour
                                                && cq.IsHoliday == false
                                            )
                                    :
                                    //No holidays found in the collection, all days are non-holidays
                                    callQuery.Where(
                                        cq => cq.Date.Date == dc.Date.Date && cq.PDay.ToLower() == dc.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToLower()
                                        && dc.Date >= cq.StartDate && dc.Date <= cq.EndDate
                                        && dchv.h >= cq.ItemStartHour && dchv.h <= cq.ItemEndHour
                                        && cq.IsHoliday == false
                                    )
                            );

                      dchv.Type = matchQuery.Select(x => x.TypeIndexes).FirstOrDefault();
                      dchv.Cost = decimal.Round(matchQuery.Select(x => x.Rate).FirstOrDefault() * (dchv.value == null ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(dchv.value)), 2);
                      dchv.Label = matchQuery.Select(x => x.Label).FirstOrDefault();
                });

                //Apply Type Grouping
                var types = dc.HourValuePairs.GroupBy(x => x.Type).Select(y => new
                {
                    Index = y.Key,
                    Value = y.Sum(z => z.value)
                });

                dc.ValueType1 = types.Where(x => x.TypeId == 1).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0m;
                dc.ValueType2 = types.Where(x => x.TypeId == 2).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0m;
                dc.ValueType2 = types.Where(x => x.TypeId == 3).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0m;
            });
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

Based on Omada's comment, I tried the following and it brought down the query execution to 1.25 seconds.

```
dataCopy.ForEach(dc =>
            {
                var callQueryWithHolidays = callQuery.Where(
                                            cq => cq.Date.Date == dc.Date.Date && cq.TOUProfileDay.ToLower() == "holiday"
                                            && dc.Date >= cq.EffectiveDate && dc.Date <= cq.EndDate
                                            && cq.IsHoliday == true
                                        ).ToList();

                var callQueryWithoutHolidays = callQuery.Where(
                                                cq => cq.Date.Date == dc.Date.Date && cq.TOUProfileDay.ToLower() == dc.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToLower()
                                                && dc.Date >= cq.EffectiveDate && dc.Date <= cq.EndDate
                                                && cq.IsHoliday == false
                                            ).ToList();

                //Apply Cost and Rate to each Hour:Value pair 
                dc.HourValuePairs.ForEach(dchv => {
                      var matchQuery =
                            (
                                //If there were holidays...
                                holidayStructureList != null
                                ?
                                    //If the day is a holiday
                                    (holidayStructureList.Select(h => h.Date.Date).Contains(dc.Date.Date)) 
                                    ?
                                        //Then ensure that the IsHoliday flag is set
                                        callQueryWithHolidays.Where(
                                            cq => dchv.h >= cq.ItemStartHour && dchv.h <= cq.ItemEndHour
                                        )
                                        :
                                            //Else, it's a regular day
                                            callQueryWithoutHolidays.Where(
                                                cq => dchv.h >= cq.ItemStartHour && dchv.h <= cq.ItemEndHour
                                            )
                                    :
                                    //No holidays found in the collection, all days are non-holidays
                                    callQueryWithoutHolidays.Where(
                                        cq => dchv.h >= cq.ItemStartHour && dchv.h <= cq.ItemEndHour
                                    )
                            );

                      dchv.Type = matchQuery.Select(x => x.TypeIndexes).FirstOrDefault();
                      dchv.Cost = decimal.Round(matchQuery.Select(x => x.Rate).FirstOrDefault() * (dchv.value == null ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(dchv.value)), 2);
                      dchv.Label = matchQuery.Select(x => x.Label).FirstOrDefault();
                });

                //Apply Type Grouping
                var types = dc.HourValuePairs.GroupBy(x => x.Type).Select(y => new
                {
                    Index = y.Key,
                    Value = y.Sum(z => z.value)
                });

                dc.ValueType1 = types.Where(x => x.TypeId == 1).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0m;
                dc.ValueType2 = types.Where(x => x.TypeId == 2).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0m;
                dc.ValueType2 = types.Where(x => x.TypeId == 3).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0m;
            });
```

Comment: Most likely you can dramatically speed things up by running all that code on in-memory objects instead of running DB queries all the time... You probably can map every hour to data first and than just find hours back via dictionary...

Comment: It looks like in your `callQuery.Where` calls, you are filtering by whether it's a holiday or not. You can do this beforehand outside the `dataCopy.ForEach` loop and make two filtered lists. Then you won't have to loop over all 792 in the inner loop.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's what I'm doing. The database queries aren't shown in this snippet since I'm using them to populate the callQuery and holidayStructureList lists beforehand. The joins are already done and the callQuery contains a day by day breakdown. The code snippet you see here is doing what you suggested (all using in-memory objects).

Comment: Since its all in-memory, there is no speed advantage to using Linq. You may as well unwind all your nested loops into procedural loops, then run the VS.net profiler on your code - at least that way you can instrument it and trace it.

Comment: @RizJa I think for you to get any better recommendations you should re-read [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post to provide initial sample setup, remove all string manipulation code, merge Where+Select+FirstOrDefault into just FirstOrDefault and likely remove all but one branch (since `if` is rarely reason of slowness).

Comment: @PhillipH changing LINQ to no-LINQ iteration is unlikely to help - code is still end up being what looks like 3 nested linear iterations... OP likely need some way to un-nest iteration...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - it will enable the OP to understand the execution path of the code - nested Linq queries are declarative and not procedural, so are not a great way to carry out performance debugging. Linq is no faster than procedural loops, and by refactoring out the nested queries you enable effective use of debugging, stepping and performance profiling. At the very least using some method calls instead of inline queries would enable a simple call count of each of the branches.

Comment: @PhillipH I see - that makes sense (will provide good educational value).

Comment: @Omada That was brilliant... your suggestion worked for me. I set up two additional lists outside the inner ForEach and filtered the results. That brought down my overall query taking 10+ seconds to 1.25 seconds! Please post that comment as an answer and I'll mark it as selected, thanks!

Comment: @PhillipH Thanks for the tip, when I can spare some time, I may just write out the query without LINQ. I agree, it'll be quite useful in performance debugging for me. For now though, Omada's suggestion seems to have done it for me. Appreciate your comments nonetheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments above:

> It looks like in your `callQuery.Where` calls, you are filtering by
>   whether it's a holiday or not. You can do this beforehand outside the
>   `dataCopy.ForEach` loop and make two filtered lists. Then you won't
>   have to loop over all 792 in the inner loop.

It seems this worked well for you! :) If you need to get it lower than 1.25 seconds you are probably going to have to do what @Alexei Levenkov suggested and start making dictionaries of your data.